# Problemas con structs y punteros en C++

Tags: c++, punteros, struct

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    struct *album{
        string title;
        Artist *artist;
        Date releaseDate;
        int num_songs;
        Song **songs;
    };
```

El compilador me saca el siguiente error:

> Declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition

He buscado el error por google pero no me salen casos que satisfagan mi duda, no se si es por "struct *album" o por que se produce, por consecuencia como se resuelve. Mi duda sobre todo está en como arreglar este error, gracias.

Comment: Puede que `Artist` y `Song` también deban ser estructuras... y de seguro no la estás definiendo...

Comment: Cierto! Ademas me he fijado en un error tontísimo que tuve, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Un objeto en C++ se define de la siguiente manera:

> `class`|`struct` *nombre* `{` *miembros* `};`

Te sobra el asterisco (`*`) que en este contexto significa crear un puntero:

> `struct` **nombre* `{` *miembros* `};`

Ahí estás dando nombre al puntero, la estructura se queda sin nombre, probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
struct Album {
    string title;
    Artist *artist;
    Date releaseDate;
    int num_songs;
    Song **songs;
};

using puntero_album = Album *;
```

Incluso mejor, olvida los punteros:

```
struct Album {
    string title;
    std::reference_wrapper<Artist> artist;
    Date releaseDate;
    // El número de canciones se puede obtener de la lista con la función ::size()
    std::list<Song> songs;
};

std::list<Album> albumes;
```